# How to examine interactions between factor and covariate in a mixed effects model?

Tags: repeated-measures, interaction, lme4-nlme, contrasts, predictor

I have 2 factors `A` and `B` (5×3) and one covariate `X` in a within subject design. Here's how I specify my overall model:

```
lme.out = lme(y~ A*B*X, random=~1|Subject, data=mydata)
```

My interpretation is that I am looking at a graph `y~x`, where the slope changes due to the covariate, and the line shifts up or down based on the different levels of `A` and `B` (changes in intercepts).

What I want to find out is: if I were to fix factor `A` (take any of the levels), then looking at the lines (`y~x`), what is the effect of `B`? Does the levels of `B` shift the line up or down (intercepts) or does it alter the slope of the line (`X`).

Should I be running some sort of contrasts analysis? But I am not sure how contrasts work between factors and covariates.

One way I could think of is to take the subsets of data corresponding to different levels of A and create models such as: `lme(y~ B+X, random=~1|Subject, data=mydata[which(mydata$A = A1,])`. This way I could compare the resulting intercepts and slopes across these models.

Can anyone tell me if what I am doing make sense? Suggestions of any kind would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want to make graphs to look at these relationships? I think that's a good idea. You can do it with `lattice` or `ggplot` or base graphics in `R` depending on what you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I did look at the graphs. Since I have hypotheses regarding how they would behave I am hoping to be able to formally analyse them.

Comment: Be aware that "My interpretation is that I am looking at a graph y~x, where the slope changes due to the covariate, and the line shifts up or down based on the different levels of A and B (changes in intercepts)." is a little of: the way your fixed effects are set up (A*B*X), you're estimating a different intercept AND SLOPE IN X for each combination of the levels of A and B.

Answer (score 1):

For visualizing interaction terms, you may look at the [sjPlot-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html) ([see examples here](http://strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.int/)).

Your function call would be

```
sjp.int(fit, type ="eff")
```

I'm not sure, however, if this meets your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that if you want to examine the true relationship between Y and the factors in your model after controlling for X you should be looking at the plotted **adjusted** rather than raw means computed from your favorite model. 
For the purposes there are R packages such as lsmeans which are quite handy and user-friendly!

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the VIFs of your model.  VIF stands for Variance Inflation Factor and is a way to measure co-linearity.

https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/347

There is a vif function in the car package for R.